# Only 1024 bytes for each /etc/environment variable :( -> rebuilding pam with larger limits?

Tags: ubuntu, environment-variables, http-proxy

I have a long list (more than 1013 chars) of hostnames and IPs in my /etc/environment `no_proxy`/`NO_PROXY` variable, because my corporate proxy does not know them. My local Unbound DNS does. Only some of that hostnames and IPs are working.

It looks like [pam_env](https://github.com/linux-pam/linux-pam/blob/master/modules/pam_env/pam_env.c) from that package limits the `var=value` (e.g. `no_proxy="blah"`) assignments to 1024 bytes each.

1. How can I get the source (`apt-get source libpam-modules`)? Which /etc/apt/sources.list `deb-src` entries do I need?
2. In which path is pam_env.c, so I can edit it? Does `updatedb && locate pam_env.c` help?
3. How do I build it and integrate it in Ubuntu 14.04 and in Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: As a non-answer / workaround, what if you set partial variables that were under 1023 bytes then combined them in a separate shell init file? `np1=a; np2=b; ...` from pam, then `final=${np1}${np2}...` ?

Comment: As a side note, your question seems to be about rebuilding pam with larger limits, so I'd recommend that be in the title.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I need my no proxy hosts not only in console but also for applications like Git, Jetty/Tomcat, Jenkins.

Comment: Maybe it is easier to have them source a separate "proxy environment" file during their startup?

Comment: You can alternatively put `. /etc/environment` in your `.profile` to read them in.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick this will only affect my console and not other applications?

Comment: It will affect virtually every program you start after you login, if the variables are `export`ed.

Comment: What about services or cronjobs?

Comment: I should've been more precise. Processes started from processes whose lineage can't be traced back your login session will either use pam_env to read in /etc/environment, with its line-length limitations, or won't read /etc/environment at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Rebuilding PAM with larger limits

Execute scripts as normal user with sudo privileges.

### Script for Ubuntu with BZR (= Bazaar) (really untested!)

Create file with `vi build_pam_via_ubuntu_and_bzr.sh`, put script in it (see below), make file executable `chmod +x build_pam_via_ubuntu_and_bzr.sh` and exec it with `./build_pam_via_ubuntu_and_bzr.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Stop when folder exists (please delete manually):
[ -e /opt/bzr/pam/ ] && exit 0

# Update sources:
sudo apt-get update || exit 1

# Install source control:
sudo apt-get install bzr bzr-builddeb -y || exit 1

# Create folder:
sudo mkdir -p /opt/bzr/pam/ || exit 1

# Change owner and group:
sudo chown -R $(id -u):$(id -g) /opt/bzr/pam/  || exit 1

# Enter folder:
cd /opt/bzr/pam/ || exit 1

# Clone PAM repo
bzr branch lp:ubuntu/vivid/pam || exit 1

# Join folder:
cd /opt/bzr/pam/ubuntu/ || exit 1

# Main point: Change BUF_SIZE limit:
sed -i "s/#define BUF_SIZE 1024/#define BUF_SIZE 8192/" modules/pam_env/pam_env.c || exit 1

# Add new version number to debian/changelog:
dch -n "Change environment variable limit from 1024 to 8192." || exit 1

# `bzr builddeb -- -uc -us` will fail with `unmet build dependencies`, install them:
sudo apt-get install libcrack2-dev debhelper quilt flex bison libfl-dev libdb-dev libselinux1-dev po-debconf dh-autoreconf autopoint libaudit-dev pkg-config xsltproc libxml2-utils docbook-xml docbook-xsl w3m -y || exit 1

# Another error lead me to remove fop (maybe not necessary):
###sudo apt-get remove fop || exit 1

# Build packages without signing them (takes ~ 20 minutes):
bzr builddeb -- -uc -us || exit 1

# Install local packages and dependencies with apt-get (possible since Ubuntu 16.04)
# Otherwise (Ubuntu 14.04) use dpkg
sudo apt-get install /opt/bzr/pam/*.deb || sudo dpkg --force-all -i /opt/bzr/pam/*.deb || exit 1

# Now you can have env variables with ~ 8192 chars:
sudo bash -c "echo 'BLUBB123=\"'$(tr -dc 'a-z0-9' < /dev/urandom | head -c8000)'\"' >> /etc/environment" || exit 1
```

### Script for Ubuntu 14.04.5 with Git (tested)

Create file with `vi build_pam_via_trusty_and_git.sh`, put script in it (see below), make file executable `chmod +x build_pam_via_trusty_and_git.sh` and exec it with `./build_pam_via_trusty_and_git.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Stop when folder exists (please delete manually):
[ -e /opt/git/pam/ ] && exit 0

# Update sources:
sudo apt-get update || exit 1

# Install source control:
sudo apt-get install git git-buildpackage -y || exit 1

# Create folder:
sudo mkdir -p /opt/git/pam/ || exit 1

# Change owner and group:
sudo chown -R $(id -u):$(id -g) /opt/git/pam/  || exit 1

# Enter folder:
cd /opt/git/pam/ || exit 1

# Clone PAM repo
git clone -b ubuntu/trusty-security https://git.launchpad.net/~usd-import-team/ubuntu/+source/pam || exit 1

# Join folder:
cd /opt/git/pam/pam/ || exit 1

# Main point: Change BUF_SIZE limit:
sed -i "s/#define BUF_SIZE 1024/#define BUF_SIZE 8192/" modules/pam_env/pam_env.c || exit 1

# Add new version number to debian/changelog (coming from 1.1.8-1ubuntu2.2):
dch -n "Change environment variable limit from 1024 to 8192." || exit 1

# Add changed files to Git index:
git add /opt/git/pam/pam/modules/pam_env/pam_env.c || exit 1
git add /opt/git/pam/pam/debian/changelog || exit 1

# Commit Git index:
git commit -m "Change environment variable limit from 1024 to 8192." || exit 1

sudo apt-get install libcrack2-dev debhelper quilt flex bison libfl-dev libdb-dev libselinux1-dev po-debconf dh-autoreconf autopoint libaudit-dev pkg-config xsltproc libxml2-utils docbook-xml docbook-xsl w3m -y || exit 1

# Another error lead me to remove fop (maybe not necessary):
###sudo apt-get remove fop || exit 1

# Build packages without signing them (takes ~ 20 minutes):
gbp buildpackage --git-debian-branch="ubuntu/trusty-security" --git-ignore-new --git-upstream-tree="ubuntu/trusty-security" -uc -us || exit 1

# Install local packages:
sudo dpkg --force-all -i /opt/git/pam/*.deb || exit 1

# Now you can have env variables with ~ 8192 chars:
sudo bash -c "echo 'BLUBB123=\"'$(tr -dc 'a-z0-9' < /dev/urandom | head -c8000)'\"' >> /etc/environment" || exit 1
```

### Script for Ubuntu 16.04.4 with Git (tested)

Create file with `vi build_pam_via_xenial_and_git.sh`, put script in it (see below), make file executable `chmod +x build_pam_via_xenial_and_git.sh` and exec it with `./build_pam_via_xenial_and_git.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Stop when folder exists (please delete manually):
[ -e /opt/git/pam/ ] && exit 0

# Update sources:
sudo apt-get update || exit 1

# Install source control:
sudo apt-get install git git-buildpackage -y || exit 1

# Create folder:
sudo mkdir -p /opt/git/pam/ || exit 1

# Change owner and group:
sudo chown -R $(id -u):$(id -g) /opt/git/pam/  || exit 1

# Enter folder:
cd /opt/git/pam/ || exit 1

# Clone PAM repo
git clone -b ubuntu/xenial https://git.launchpad.net/~usd-import-team/ubuntu/+source/pam || exit 1

# Join folder:
cd /opt/git/pam/pam/ || exit 1

# Main point: Change BUF_SIZE limit:
sed -i "s/#define BUF_SIZE 1024/#define BUF_SIZE 8192/" modules/pam_env/pam_env.c || exit 1

# Add new version number to debian/changelog (coming from 1.1.8-3.2ubuntu2.1):
dch --distribution unstable --package "pam" --newversion "1.1.8-3.2ubuntu2.2" "Change environment variable limit from 1024 to 8192." || exit 1
# dch -n "Change environment variable limit from 1024 to 8192." || exit 1

# Add changed files to Git index:
git add /opt/git/pam/pam/modules/pam_env/pam_env.c || exit 1
git add /opt/git/pam/pam/debian/changelog || exit 1

# Commit Git index:
git commit -m "Change environment variable limit from 1024 to 8192." || exit 1

sudo apt-get install libcrack2-dev debhelper quilt flex bison libfl-dev libdb-dev libselinux1-dev po-debconf dh-autoreconf autopoint libaudit-dev pkg-config xsltproc libxml2-utils docbook-xml docbook-xsl w3m -y || exit 1

# Another error lead me to remove fop (maybe not necessary):
###sudo apt-get remove fop || exit 1

# Build packages without signing them (takes ~ 20 minutes):
gbp buildpackage --git-debian-branch="ubuntu/xenial" --git-ignore-new --git-upstream-tree="ubuntu/xenial" -uc -us || exit 1

# Install local packages and dependencies with apt-get (possible since Ubuntu 16.04):
sudo apt-get install /opt/git/pam/*.deb -y || exit 1

# Now you can have env variables with ~ 8192 chars:
sudo bash -c "echo 'BLUBB123=\"'$(tr -dc 'a-z0-9' < /dev/urandom | head -c8000)'\"' >> /etc/environment" || exit 1
```

### Testing

Reboot your machine (maybe not necessary):

```
sudo reboot
```

Check installed version number:

```
sudo apt install apt-show-versions
sudo apt-show-versions libpam-modules
```

returns something like

```
libpam-modules:amd64 1.1.8-3.2ubuntu2.1 newer than version in archive
libpam-modules:i386 not installed
```

which is correct.

Reconnect and show env var BLUBB123 with 8000 chars:

```
echo $BLUBB123
```

---

Related to:

1. https://github.com/linux-pam/linux-pam/issues/31
2. [What happens to self-built packages when I `apt dist-upgrade`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/382981/what-happens-to-self-built-packages-when-i-apt-dist-upgrade)

Comment: You can use `set -e` in your scripts to avoid all the `|| exit 1` statements. Check out `dch --nmu`, it will produce a valid, newer version regardless of what the current version is, so you don’t need to hard-code a version number in your script.

Comment: Hehe, I am coming from Python with [explicit is better than implicit](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) and `set -e` has side-effects. I will check `dch --nmu`.

Comment: First: `dch --help` states that `dch --nmu` is the same as `dch -n`. Second: If you want that no editor (like vim, nano, mcedit) is shown (non-interactive/console only), give a message behind, like `dch -n "foobar"`.

Comment: My point was to use `--nmu` (or `-n`) instead of hard-coding a version with `--newversion`, that’s all.