# What happens to self-built packages when I `apt dist-upgrade`?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, dpkg

I installed some self-built deb packages (PAM) with

```
sudo dpkg --force-all -i /opt/bzr/build-area/*.deb
```

`tree` is:

```
/opt/bzr/build-area 
.
├── libpam0g_1.1.8-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
├── libpam0g-dev_1.1.8-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
├── libpam-cracklib_1.1.8-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
├── libpam-doc_1.1.8-3ubuntu1_all.deb
├── libpam-modules_1.1.8-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
├── libpam-modules-bin_1.1.8-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
├── libpam-runtime_1.1.8-3ubuntu1_all.deb
├── pam_1.1.8-3ubuntu1_amd64.build
├── pam_1.1.8-3ubuntu1_amd64.changes
├── pam_1.1.8-3ubuntu1.diff.gz
├── pam_1.1.8-3ubuntu1.dsc
└── pam_1.1.8.orig.tar.gz
```

1. Important: What happens when a new official Ubuntu PAM version is released and I run `apt dist-upgrade -y`? Will it overwrite my own packages?
2. Optional: Do I need `--force-all` in `dpkg -i`?
3. Optional: https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-core-dev/pam/ubuntu looks like a "dev branch" to me? Does a "stable branch" exist? How to get it with bzr?

Related to: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/382363/239596

Comment: if you don't want them upgraded you can mark them as held with `apt-mark hold libpam0g libpam0g-dev libpam-cracklib libpam-doc libpam-modules libpam-modules-bin libpam-runtime` (and unhold them with `apt-mark unhold ...`).    This will probably cause numerous other packages that depend on newer pam packages to also be held.  You're better off downloading the source package for the new version of pam, patching it again, compiling and installing.  *Then* use apt-mark to hold them (until the next time this needs to be done).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, they will, if they use a higher version number than your packages, unless you adjust your pin priorities appropriately (or hold the packages, as pointed out by [cas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/7696/cas)). Note that the repositories’ packages are liable to overwrite yours if you use the same version number, so you should really increment your version when you rebuild locally (typically “1.1.8-3ubuntu1.1”).
2. No, and you should avoid it unless absolutely necessary. If you think it’s necessary, there’s probably something wrong with your packages and you should fix that instead.
3. That code repository hasn’t been updated since 2014, so I doubt it’s an active development repository. You can see the various `pam` branches on [Launchpad](https://code.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pam), and clone them using for example `bzr branch lp:ubuntu/vivid/pam`.

The way I go about dealing with this type of situation is as follows:

- check out the source code (`debcheckout` or `apt-get source`)
- if it’s in a repository, create a new branch with the patch I’m interested in
- if it’s not, apply the patch manually
- in both cases, increment the version with an appropriate changelog entry using `dch -n` (without committing it, to avoid merge issues)
- build the package and install it (in my case, *via* a local package repository)

When a new version of the package is released, I repeat the above; in the case of a source repository, I rebase the patch instead of starting from scratch.

Comment: Thanks. I updated https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/382363/239596. Is `git clone -b ubuntu/xenial https://git.launchpad.net/~usd-import-team/ubuntu/+source/pam` or with `ubuntu/trusty` a good source?

Comment: The first git repo you mention is listed on the page I linked to (*via* the “View git repositories” link), so I’d imagine it’s OK.

Comment: Cool. Maybe I write a "checker" to get info via mail about new versions. I guess they have no RSS feed or something similar?

Comment: It looks like they don’t.